# Understanding the proof of $~M$ invariant set $\Rightarrow$ subtangential condition holds

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, invariance

**Problem:**

I want to understand a proof of the claim given in the title. Suppose we have an initial value problem $\{\dot{x}=f(t,x)~,~x(t_0)=x_0\}$ with continious $f$ and solution $x(t)$.

> *Proof:*
>
> If $M$ is a positive invariant set and $x_0 \in M$, then for $h>0$ small enough
>   $$\mathrm{dist}(x_0+hf(t_0,x_0),M)\leq |x_0+hf(t_0,x_0)-x(t_0+h)|_2.$$
>   [...]
>
> So for every $\varepsilon > 0$ one can find  a $\delta >0$ such that
>   $$\mathrm{dist}(x_0+hf(t_0,x_0),M)\leq \left| h\dot{x}(t_0)-\int_{t_0}^{t_0+h}\dot{x}(s)ds \right| _2\color{red}{\leq}\varepsilon h,$$
>   whenever $h\in (0,\delta]$.
>
> (So we showed that $\lim_{h \searrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\mathrm{dist}(x+hf(t,x),M)=0$ for every $ t\in\mathbb{R},x\in M$.)

**Attempt:**

I understand everything except the red part above. I see that

$$\left| h\dot{x}(t_0)-\int_{t_0}^{t_0+h}\dot{x}(s)ds \right| _2\overset{\color{red}{\text{ed.:wrong!}}}{\neq}{\scriptsize h\dot{x}(t_0)-\dot{x}(t_0+h)+\dot{x}(t_0)=\underbrace{(h+1)}_{\to 1}\dot{x}(t_0)-\dot{x}(\underbrace{t_0+h}_{\to t_0})\overset{?}{\to}0}$$

<s>(where $\to$ means $\overset{h\searrow 0}{\longrightarrow}$ to be precise) which might be wrong/unhelpful since there's no $\frac{1}{h}$ in front. On the other hand $\dot{x}$ is continious so there should be no problem when pushing the limit around, so probably that's just not the right approach.</s> I messed up here multiple times, corrected in my answer below.

**Questions:**

1) I feel like I'm missing out on something completely obvious here, help would be much appreciated. If needed, I can provide the "[...]" above, but I don't feel like that will be important...
2) A few lines below the author says "This [that the subt. cond. holds] is clear for every $x\in \mathring{M}$.". How is that clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

$$\left| h\dot{x}(t_0)-\int_{t_0}^{t_0+h}\dot{x}(s)ds \right| _2=h\dot{x}(t_0)-(x(t_0+h)-x(t_0))=h\bigg(\dot{x}(t_0)-\underbrace{\frac{x(t_0+h)-x(t_0)}{h}}_{\longrightarrow\dot{x}(t_0)\text{ for } h\searrow 0}\bigg)$$

Too much text for such a simple mistake, I feel sorry. Hope noone bothered.